# How can I access a resource on our company VPN from inside a devcontainer?

Tags: vscode-devcontainer

Our company has stood up an instance of hashicorp vault on the company VPN at https://vault.company.io and in order to make use of it from the command-line I need to run:

`VAULT_ADDR=https://vault.company.io vault login -method=oidc -namespace=my-namespace --token-only`

which authenticates to https://vault.company.io and retrieves a token that I can then use for subsequent operations against this vault instance.

When I run that from my host machine it works fine, however when I try to run from inside a devcontainer it fails with:

> Error authenticating: Put "https://vault.company.io/v1/auth/oidc/oidc/auth_url": dial tcp 172.21.20.172:443: connect: no route to host

Note that I do have a working connection to the internet from inside the devcontainer, `curl www.google.com` works fine, for example. If I try similar for the resource I'm trying to reach:

`curl https://vault.company.io`

it fails with:

> curl: (7) Failed to connect to vault.secrets.hellofresh.io port 443: No route to host

Running that same command from the host works fine.

I have done some searching about this problem and found a number of places that advised me to add:

`"runArgs": ["--network=host"]`

to my devcontainer.json but I've tried that, it didn't make any difference.

Can anyone suggest what I need to do to be able to connect to this resource on the VPN from inside my devcontainer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had a rogue docker network hanging around. After executing `docker network prune` on the host everything started working.